# creating patch from code or existing jar / classes

Tags: java, jar, patch, executable-jar

Requirement: 
To create a patch (with required classes alone)

I tried like this:

- Generated a jar using maven.
- Copied few class files manually to `path/to/files` folder
- Then created a new jar file using command `jar cvf patch.jar -C path/to/files`

When I decompile the class files via Intellij from the first jar's class files, I could see the correct code more or less. But when I  check from the second jar file the code is different.

Is it because in the second jar it is being compiled into byte format again? If so are there any consequence of this? The reason why I create a second jar is because I only need those specific class files in the folder as we use it as a patch.

Or is there any way to create a patch?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your actual need is to create a patch. I guess there would be another ways to do it. Anyways, it's better to change the question (subject) as `creating patch from existing jar` or so to get a better reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion.

- Do not create a jar from another class files / jar.
- Do create a new jar with your required class using maven itself.

**How?**

- Create a copy of your project folder
- Rename the artifact as `patch-of-your-project-name`
- Now remove unwanted classes (or say, keep your required files alone)
- Do maven build to create Jar (the new jar name will be `patch-of-...`

This way, build errors can be noted/logged easily and you can also automate the process by providing the required files list to a script and then do the maven build.

**Note:**
There's a maven plugin `maven-patch-plugin`. Please check if you can make use of it.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-patch-plugin/

---

**Remove from the jar**
A jar is just a zip file after all. Remove a single file from existing jar. Definitely much faster than uncompressing/recompressing too.

```
zip -d file.jar unwanted_file.txt
```

**Add to the jar**
Add class to a new jar

```
jar uf C:\folder\where\jar\is\the_jar_file.jar file.class
```

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate why I should not be doing it this way? This issue with the way you suggested is that there are hundreds of dependency. Its legacy code so is very difficult to do as suggested. Easiest option I found is my way or to use eclipse to generate specific jar. Both cases files and code were the same.

Comment: @Coder123, an already compiled class should not be / can not be compiled again. If you have done it, there must have happen some mistakes. I have updated my answer with details on how you can add/remove classes to/from jar. Please go through.

Comment: Either extract the jar file and add your required classes to a new jar using the command. Or remove unwanted files from existing jar.